# ORA-02270: no matching unique or primary key for this column-list in my oracle code

Tags: oracle

```
create table tbl_jawad_artist(
artist_id varchar2(5),
artist_name varchar2(25));

create table tbl_jawad_gallery(
painting_id varchar2(5),
paintng_type varchar2(10),
painting_name varchar2(49),
artist_id varchar2(5),

constraint PK_paint primary key(painting_id,artist_id)
);
alter table tbl_jawad_gallery add constraint fk_paint
  foreign key(artist_id)references tbl_jawad_artist(artist_id);
```

Comment: Without information on `tbl_jawad_gallery` it's hard to say what is the problem. You should be able to fix your issue easily reading this : http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora02270.php else add more info.

Answer (score 0):

The error is fairly clear; your `tbl_jawad_artist` table doesn't have `artist_id` defined as the primary key (or a unique key), so `references tbl_jawad_artist(artist_id)` isn't valid.

You need to add a suitable key to the parent table:

```
create table tbl_jawad_artist(
  artist_id varchar2(5),
  artist_name varchar2(25),
  constraint PK_artist primary key(artist_id)
);

Table tbl_jawad_artist created.

create table tbl_jawad_gallery(
  painting_id varchar2(5),
  painting_type varchar2(10),
  painting_name varchar2(49),
  artist_id varchar2(5),
  constraint PK_gallery primary key(painting_id,artist_id)
);

Table tbl_jawad_gallery created.

alter table tbl_jawad_gallery
  add constraint fk_paint foreign key(artist_id)
    references tbl_jawad_artist(artist_id);

Table tbl_jawad_gallery altered.
```

You can include the foreign key in the table creation statement if you want, it doesn't need to be a separate `alter`.

I'm not sure this model makes sense; seems odd to have the artist/painting as a compound key, and the primary key on `tnl_jawad_gallery` just being on `painting_id` might be better, but it depends how you're using this I suppose. It looks more like a 'painting' table than a 'gallery' table, though.